# jquery ui multiselect checkbox select

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, multi-select

I have a jquery ui multiselect dropdown. I want to check one of the checkboxes in the code. I used this code:

```
$("#selector option").each(function() {
                if ($(this).val() == "EDIT"){
                    $(this).attr("checked","checked");
                 }else{
                     $(this).attr("selected", false);

                 }
            });
```

This code doesn't work. In the console I see isContentEditable: false. Is this the issue? If yes, how can I solve it?

**UPDATE:**

I also used this:

```
$("selector").multiselect("widget").find(":checkbox[value='EDIT']").each(function() {
            $(this).attr("checked",true);
        });
```

But it doesn't work!

Comment: `this` in your code will refer to the `option` element, not a checkbox. You need to change the selector for the `attr()` method use.

Comment: Are you able to mark the checkbox checked?

Comment: @Learning yes, I can.

Comment: See my answer below, If that is helpful then mark as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code will work if you use .click() trigger too.

```
$("selector").multiselect("widget").find(":checkbox[value='EDIT']").each(function() {
            $(this).attr("checked",true).click();
        });
```

Only `checked="true"` will not trigger the `"click"` event of checkbox. You explicitly have to fire it.